# Convert to Date m d yy?

Tags: c#, date, webforms, converters

I have two text boxes that are connected to a jquery Datepicker. When a date is pick the date will appear in the text box as format `d m yy` e.g. 10 oct 2013. Ive looked around and found alot about converting to date but not from this format, is there any way this can be done?

Comment: "10 oct 2013" looks more like `"d MMM yyyy"`.

Comment: check this for reference, http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats. I know it looks like MMM but M will actually display as e.g. oct

Comment: `"d MMM yyyy"` is the .Net format string of that date. The format string of the jquery datepicker doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is `10 oct 2013` as mentioned, you convert a real `DateTime` to such string in this way:

```
string format = "dd MMM yyyy";
string result = dt.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // maybe ToLower according to your string
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` forces english language even with a different culture.

If you  need to parse it from `string` to `DateTime` use `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10 oct 2013", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but when i tried DateTime.ParseExact i get the following error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'.

Comment: @Srb1313711: Not with `10 oct 2013`, what string have you used?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `"dd MMM yyyy"` format.

[`dd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) is for day from 01 through 31, [`MMM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier) is for abbreviated name of the month and [`yyyy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yyyyySpecifier) is for year as a four-digit number.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

For example;

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 10, 10);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output will be;

```
10 Oct 2013
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/mudRe8)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting your string as follows?

```
txtBox.ToString("d M yy");
```

oops, I meant

```
dateTime.ToString("d M yy");
```

Comment: I don't think that will compile, ToString() on a textbox does not have an overload that takes a string.